# Convert data into json format in REST Webservice

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest

I have implemented json parsing in my android app.Now I want to learn REST using json.I have googled it and got the code.Its working fine.I want to clarify one thing in the code.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json");
    }
```

In the code they have converted data into json extension(in the url).How to convert the data in json extension.Suppose if I have data in php format so how to convert it in json extension?

Answer (score 0):

Json extension doesnt have any relation with response it just a url extension can be any thing like php or nothing

Below are some json url examples :

**Extension with php**

```
http://androidjson.itweb-projects.com/categories.php
```

**Entension with txt**

```
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt
```

No Extension

```
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/
```

Comment: @DIVA- so it means that in our url it can be anything in REST webservice.I am talking about REST not of json

Comment: @AnushkaAgarwal yes i mean rest url can be anything ..rest is basically a protocol

Comment: u can create any sample project and use above url and parse it via json or gson

Answer (score 0):

.json extension does not exist i think.

In your php :

You can create an array like

```
$tab = new array();
```

Then you can put your data in this array.

```
$tab["key"] = $yourData;
```

Then when your array is full, call

```
print(json_encode($tab));
```

It will encode your array to a JSON array.

In JAVA you can get data from JSONArray easily :)